# How to clear cookies when logging out of firebase?

Tags: javascript, cookies, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a log out button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick=logUserOut() value="Log out">
```

and am using the firebase sign out method

```
function logUserOut(){
      firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        console.log("Sign-out successful.");
      }, function(error) {
        console.log("An error happened.");
      });
    }
```

but in the console before I log out and after I log out when I type

```
document.cookie
```

I get

```
"useruid=GH39ayyIFkaBrEe2JpsXWtPyZRG2"
```

Surely this should clear cookies? and if not, how can i do this?

Comment: so, firebase creates this cookie when you log in?

Comment: Don't know about firebase, but logout does not necessarely deletes the cookie at client side, it rather invalidate the cookie content at the server side (the cookie is still present but the server refuse it).

Comment: yes firebase creates the cookie and Alexandre might be right as im only mocking the server side of things so cant properly tell if it would be refused

Comment: No cookies are created by Firebase auth. You must have this cookie set from some other library.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication uses your browser's local storage to track the sign-in state of the user. It adds a token there when the user signs in **and** removes the token when the user signs out.

Firebase Authentication does not use cookies to store the authentication state.

To verify this, I quickly ran the following in my Chrome developer console:

> ```
> app.auth().currentUser.uid
> ```
>
> "AxeiivC30ANFoGVWRDL3yEV6mhK2"
>
> ```
> document.cookie
> ```
>
> ""